# Html markup test page for testing html renderers

Tags: html, richtextbox, wysiwyg

I'm looking for example html code for testing some html editor's render. Is there any sample page(s) used for that kind of jobs? what is the best practice?

Comment: How is that a wpf question exactly?

Comment: How about going to any website in any browser and right clicking and then selecting the `View source` option to *view the HTML source code*?

Comment: I would remove WPF from this question, it's a valid question but we're all mean in this tag and you're setting yourself up for down votes and being closed.

Comment: I have removed the unrelated WPF tag from this question.

Comment: I am researching html editors for wpf. and i check rendering compabilities and features.